# Numerical differentiation of a function of many variables

Tags: java, math, numerical-methods, differentiation

I have to count this.

[image]

in this way

[image]

I chose the second method.

But I'm not at all sure if I did it right.But I think not.Because I don't even understand how to count it on a piece of paper. At the same time, I was told to calculate it with a given accuracy, which is accepted from the keyboard.I understand that I have to calculate the derivative, then reduce the delta, and calculate the derivative again. And until the difference between these two values becomes less than epsilon.but I would like to deal with this first....

I will be very grateful for your help, because my head is already boiling.

That's what the program brought out. But I don't even know if it is or not, because I can't even count it with my hands. I'm sorry if this task is simple for you, but I'm stupid.

[image]

Please tell me.I am at a loss how to implement this.

```
public class Cmath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("enter the num of the variables");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        double[] variables = new double[number];
        double[] deltas = new double[number];
        double[] variables_after_f = new double[number];
        double[] variables_after_dif = new double[number];
        double[] sum= new double[number];
        double[] minus= new double[number];
        //Function_of_many_variables test_f = new Function_of_many_variables(variables);
        //System.out.println ("enter the values of the variables");
        for (int i =0 ; i<number; i++) {
            variables [i] = scanner.nextDouble();
            variables_after_f [i] =function(variables [i]); 
            // just checking if my function x^2 work correctly
            System.out.println(variables_after_f [i]);
        }
        System.out.println ("enter the values of the deltas ");
        for (int i =0 ; i<number; i++) {
            deltas [i] = 0.1;
        }
        for (int i =0 ; i<number; i++) {
            
            for (int m = 0, k = 0, p = i; p<number ;m++,k++, p++){
                sum[m] = variables [k]+deltas[p];
                minus[m]=variables [k]-deltas[p];
                variables_after_dif [i]= der (sum[m],minus[m],deltas[p]);
            }
            
        }
        

        for (int i = 0 ; i < number; i++) {
            System.out.println(variables_after_dif [i]);
        }
    }

    public static double function(double xin) {
          double out = 0;
            out = Math.pow(xin, 2);
          return out;
    }
    public static double der(double f1, double f2,double del){
        double out = (function(f1) - function(f2))/(2*del);
        return out;
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not know java, but I know calculus. The two methods are equivalent. But I see some confusion after that. I *strongly* recommend that you write code to calculate the derivative of a function of one variable, before you attempt a function of several variables.

Comment: @Beta I tried to write a program for one variable.And it works right. But  this broke my brain. it's not even a matter of knowing java.I just can't make a calculation algorithm. That's exactly the problem.

Comment: You succeeded in devising a calculation algorithm for one variable. You calculate a derivative by applying a delta to x, then do it again with a smaller delta, and quit when the results are very similar. Now try two variables, x1 and x2. Calculate a derivative by applying a delta to x1 (leaving x2 unchanged), do it again with a smaller delta, quit when the results are very similar, and you have f/x1.

Comment: If it helps, you can think of it this way: F3(z) = f(x1, x2, z, x4, x5, ..., xn). So f/x3 = F3/z = dF3/dz. That's a derivative of F3, which is a function of one variable, and you already know how to do that.